# This code is compiling for my colleague, but not for me

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A colleague and I are running into a situation where code is compiling for one of us, and not the other, in our Typescript-driven Angular 2 app. The code in question is this block here:

```
        // Internal function used to insert schedule
        let __insert = function (scheduleTime)
        {
            // Confirm before adding schedule
            if (this.confirmCallback)
            {
                let isCanceled = false;

                this.confirmCallback({
                    schedule: scheduleTime,
                    cancel: function ()
                    {
                        isCanceled = true;
                    }
                });

                // Return if insert is canceled
                if (isCanceled == true)
                {
                    this.editingEvent = null; // Reset edit event
                    return;
                }
            }
```

The specific line producing an error for me is this one:

```
if (isCanceled == true)
```

I get the following error pertaining to the above code:

> ERROR in ... Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'false' and
>   'true'.

My colleague gets no such error, and is thinking this must be an IDE issue. I have checked, and it's not a Lint setting. And even if my IDE didn't like it, it should still compile if it's valid JS. So we're trying to track down why this would be.

In the meantime we're using a solution where we're just checking for "truthiness", by doing this:

```
if (isCanceled)
```

But, as my colleague points out, this check isn't as robust.

The question is: why am I getting a compliation error here while he is not? Is this a Typescript-specific issue? Something else? Should this code compile?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version of the TS compiler?

Comment: Probably goes without saying but: assuming that `isCanceled` is only boolean, `false` is "falsy"

Comment: But "true" and "truthy" are not the same. Nor is "false" and "falsy". That's his point. One is more robust that the other.

Comment: As I mention above, we did settle on (isCancelled). But I'm curious as to why the first one won't compile. Should that produce an error, or not? And does it depend perhaps on something like us using two different versions of TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [bug #12772](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12772) I'd say you and your colleague are running different Typescript compiler versions (probably 2.0 and 2.1 - this is when things broke for the OP of the mentioned ticket).

The comment from the bug explains why this happens (I adjusted the variable names to fit your snippet):

> Following the control flow `isCanceled` does not seem to be assigned any value other than `false`. the function expression is not considered part of the flow, since it is not guaranteed to execute. the result is at the condition `isCanceled` has the type `false` and the check is considered invalid.
>
> A workaround would be to either cast to boolean as var `isCanceled = false as boolean` which widens the type of the variable form just `false` to `true | false`. or change the check to be for truthiness `if (isCanceled)`.
>
> Please see [#12729](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12729) for more details.

So it seems a type inference/control flow design limitation introduced somewhere around 2.1 version of the TS compiler. You can read more about TypeScript's type inference and control flow analysis limitations and trade-offs in [the ticket #9998](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

Comment: Much appreciated, Jannis.